# How to get the received time of each packet in NS-3? (802.11n+MIMO example)

Tags: ns-3

I am using this example : https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/examples/wireless/80211n-mimo.cc
and i want to get the received time of packets to be plotted. I tried to use **Simulator::Now().GetSeconds();** but it shows the same value every time (6s)
I ask if there's any other way to solve this please.

```
    /* Setting applications */
      ApplicationContainer serverApp;
      if (udp)
        {
          //UDP flow
          uint16_t port = 9;
          UdpServerHelper server (port);
          serverApp = server.Install (wifiStaNode.Get (0));
          serverApp.Start (Seconds (0.0));
          serverApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));

          UdpClientHelper client (staNodeInterface.GetAddress (0), port);
          client.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (4294967295u));
          client.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Time ("0.00001"))); //packets/s
          client.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (payloadSize));
          ApplicationContainer clientApp = client.Install (wifiApNode.Get (0));
          clientApp.Start (Seconds (1.0));
          clientApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));
        }
      else
        {
          //TCP flow
          uint16_t port = 50000;
          Address localAddress (InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), port));
          PacketSinkHelper packetSinkHelper ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory", localAddress);
          serverApp = packetSinkHelper.Install (wifiStaNode.Get (0));
          serverApp.Start (Seconds (0.0));
          serverApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));

          OnOffHelper onoff ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory",Ipv4Address::GetAny ());
          onoff.SetAttribute ("OnTime",  StringValue ("ns3::ConstantRandomVariable[Constant=1]"));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("OffTime", StringValue ("ns3::ConstantRandomVariable[Constant=0]"));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (payloadSize));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (1000000000)); //bit/s
          AddressValue remoteAddress (InetSocketAddress (staNodeInterface.GetAddress (0), port));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("Remote", remoteAddress);
          ApplicationContainer clientApp = onoff.Install (wifiApNode.Get (0));
          clientApp.Start (Seconds (1.0));
          clientApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));
        }        

    Simulator::Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));
      Simulator::Run ();

      double throughput = 0;

    **double received = Simulator::Now().GetSeconds();**

      if (udp)
        {
          //UDP
          uint64_t totalPacketsThrough = DynamicCast<UdpServer> (serverApp.Get (0))->GetReceived ();
          throughput = totalPacketsThrough * payloadSize * 8 / (simulationTime * 1000000.0); //Mbit/s
        }
      else
        {
          //TCP
          uint64_t totalPacketsThrough = DynamicCast<PacketSink> (serverApp.Get (0))->GetTotalRx ();
          throughput = totalPacketsThrough * 8 / (simulationTime * 1000000.0); //Mbit/s
        }
      dataset.Add (d, throughput);
      std::cout << throughput << " Mbit/s" << std::endl;

    **std::cout << "received After :" << received << " s" << std::endl;**

      d += step;
      Simulator::Destroy ();
    }
  plot.AddDataset (dataset);
}
```

I tried to use "Simulator::Now().GetSeconds();" but it shows the same value every time(6s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same value is returned by `Simulator::Now().GetSeconds()` because it is being called after the simulation is complete. It has to be invoked **during** the actual simulation. One way would be to actually dig around the huge library of code (TCP/UDP modules under 'src/internet/', in this case) and figure out which function actually deals with the reception of the packet. But to make life easier, ns-3 has already implemented [tracing](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/tracing.html) to handle this.

To answer your specific question, you will require a packet sink trace.

Consider the code where you are installing the packet sink inside your main() function:

```
ApplicationContainer TcpSinkApps = TcpPacketSink.Install (nodeContainer.Get(0));
Ptr<PacketSink> pktSink = StaticCast<PacketSink> (TcpSinkApps.Get(0));
std::stringstream ss; ss << "Some information";
pktSink->TraceConnect("Rx", ss.str(), MakeCallback (&SinkRxTrace));
```

The "Rx" trace is defined in [packet-sink.cc](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/packet-sink_8cc_source.html), such that SinkRxTrace() is a function that is called every time a packet is received successfully. Now you can go ahead and define the SinkRxTrace() in your code (above main() of course):

```
void SinkRxTrace(std::string context, Ptr<const Packet> pkt, const Address &addr)
{
  std::cout<<"Packet received at "<<Simulator::Now().GetSeconds()<<" s\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi @V-Red, thanks for your reply, so i tried this solution but it doesn't show anything. Also i need to get the time into a variable to be plotted not to print it with std::cout. This is what i have changed : (did i missed something?) : ' Simulator::Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));
          Simulator::Run ();
           Ptr<PacketSink> pktSink = StaticCast<PacketSink> (serverApp.Get (0));
           std::stringstream ss; ss << "Some information";
           pktSink->TraceConnect("Rx", ss.str(), MakeCallback (&SinkRxTrace)); 
           d += step;
           Simulator::Destroy ();'

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong with the simulation setup itself, and the packets are not being received, which in turn means SinkRxTrace() is never called. Try creating a pcap file or using flowmonitor to check if your simulation is working as expected.

Comment: Hi @V-Red , i am sure that the simulation is working properly, but you are right : SinkRxTrace() is never called. Also i have defineded the SinkRxTrace() above main(). I must have missed something. i included the application setup in the code. please take a look at it. thank you very much.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have the statements for tracing with SinkRxTrace(). Have you set up the trace as I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Hi @V-Red, your solution has worked perfectly finally, thank you very much, you helped me a lot :))